# I receive a 502 Bad Gateway occasionally during the execution of my node.js app on IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am running a node.js app on Bluemix which basically is a REST API for read/write operations on a Cloudant (CouchDb) database.
Incoming requests are authenticated by an injected passport-http-bearer strategy middleware into the express framework. My app uses the bearer token to receive information about the user.

This is not very performant at the moment (we are working on a caching mechanism), but in general it works. When I send much requests in parallel (e.g. in function tests), sometimes I receive the 502 Bad Gateway response instead of the expected results, which fails nearly every test suite run. On my local deployment it works without problems.

Comment: Should this perhaps be moved to http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Can we see a snippet from the log please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have a scaling issue? When you say many parallel requests - is it possible that the service reply times go beyond that what router expects (120 seconds I think) with many requests?

Can you try to push your app a little harder with Apache Bench maybe?

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 -s 120 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://your-app/
```

And then in parallel check responses with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
BEARER=<your-token>
URL=<your-app>
TIMEFORMAT="TIME: %E"

while true; do R=$(time echo -e REQUEST: $(date)\\nREPLY: $(curl -X GET -s --insecure --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" "https://$URL") 2>>trace); echo "$R" >>trace; echo $R|grep -q "502" && echo -e "Found 502 reply\n$R"; done
```

HP

Comment: Okay, that did work. 
My authorization function is calling another HTTP service for information. This other service is responding sometimes very slow. If I run multiple requests in parallel, the requests are waiting in the background and are not responding to the request. If they will take over 120 seconds, the Bluemix Loadbalancer returns with a 502 Bad Gateway.
I have done the implementation of the cache now, so this will not be a problem any more.
Thank you for your help
Konrad

Answer (score 2):

@Jeff-Sloyer is correct in suggesting retry logic in your push script.  Additionally, you should check the status of the runtime and any services being used on the Bluemix status page.  For more information on why you may be receiving this error, please see the information noted below:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/managingapps.html

Comment: I do not have 502 HTTP Responses during the push, the push is working fine, they are appearing during the runtime of the app. After some minutes they are gone again, without doing a redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this with unreliable networking.  I would use some retry login for your push script to guarantee a deploy.